# Proving that a unit disc is open in $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove part $(i)$ here.
[image]

**The following is my attempt at the problem is it correct?**

*Proof.* Let $\alpha = (a,b)\in D$ and $\beta = (x,y)\in R_{(a,b)}$ and $O = (0,0)$, then given the description of $R_{(a,b)}$ in the above proposition we have 
$$R_{(a,b)} = \left\{(x,y)\in\mathbf{R}^2:|x-a|<\frac{1-r}{8\sqrt{2}}\text{ and }|y-b|<\frac{1-r}{8\sqrt{2}}\right\}$$
implying
$$|x-a|^2 = (x-a)^2<\left(\frac{1-r}{8\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$$
$$|y-b|^2 = (y-b)^2<\left(\frac{1-r}{8\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$$
thus 
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2<2\left(\frac{1-r}{8\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1-r}{8}\right)^2<(1-r)^2$$
but then 
$$d(\alpha,\beta) = \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\sqrt{(1-r)^2} = 1-r$$

appealing to the triangle inequality implies that

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = d(O,\beta)\leq d(O,\alpha)+d(\alpha,\beta)<r+(1-r) = 1$$ the result in question then is evident.

$\blacksquare$

Given this i think it should be easy to prove that $D = \bigcup_{(a,b)\in D}R_{(a,b)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. And, since you always have $R_{(a,b)}\subset D$, then$$D=\bigcup_{(a,b)\in D}\bigl\{(a,b)\bigr\}\subset\bigcup_{(a,b)\in D}R_{(a,b)}\subset D$$and therefore $\bigcup_{(a,b)\in D}R_{(a,b)}=D$ indeed.